# How to Implement a Word Cloud on a layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, word-cloud

I found Tag-Cloud but I think it is not yet ready. Does anyone have any word cloud generator libraries available that allows you to customize it's design?

I have found this and it seems usable:

https://github.com/sschwieb/Cloudio
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest/Cloudio
https://code.google.com/p/memeplex/source/browse/trunk/Android/src/kr/ac/yonsei/memeplex/view/TagCloudLayout.java?r=31

Though it might need to be changed or edited a little. I hope somebody can help me. I will be offering bounties in the next few hours

If you can offer any algorithms I will gladly study it as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what your actual requirements are, you could use a really nice and customisable javascript word cloud written in D3 like https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud and then embed it in a WebView in your Android app. There is an example on how to do that at https://github.com/mitchwongho/D3Android

Here is a simple example I made demonstrating this https://github.com/rbarbantan/android-word-cloud

Comment: I understood it a little. But I don't know what the main.html does. And where is the `d3.layout.cloud()` call? Sorry can you expound on that part?

Comment: The https://github.com/mitchwongho/D3Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mitchwongho/d3/MainActivity.java is just an example on how to load a html page in your android app. The method of interest is onResume() where the main.html is loaded in a WebView. In your case the main.html should have the contents from https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html . That's basically an html page where you render with D3 javascript the word cloud you are interested in.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a sample project demonstrating this

Comment: Hello @Rares Can you please tell me how I can add words onto the wordcloud programmatically in your example?

Comment: I have updated my example on GitHub to load the wordcloud from Android instead of JavaScript

Comment: Thanks @RaresBarbantan!